# Easymock stub helper methods

Tags: java, methods, helper, easymock, stub

I'm trying to find a way to use EasyMock to test only a method execute() in class Foo, expect the number of times a method in a Mock object is invoked by that method, but ignoring the number of times the same method in the mock object is invoked by the helper methods of the same class Foo when called by method execute().  Because I have other test methods to test the helper methods, and just want to limit my testing to one method, not other methods when called in the same class.

The way I have it now, the test would fail because cust.getAccount() is executed more than 1 by execute(), method1() and method2().

For example:

### class under test

```
public class Foo{

    private Customer cust;   <<< this will be mocked

    public void execute(){
        cust.getAccount();  <<< this will be expected as 1 for execute()
        ...
        ...
        method1();  <<< calling helper method 1
        ...
    }

    protected method1(){
        for (...){
            cust.getAccount();
        }

        method2();   <<< calling helper method 2
    }

    method 2(){
        cust.getAccount();
    }

}
```

### Testing class

```
public class TestFoo{

    @Test
    public void testExecute(){
        Customer custMock = createMock(Customer.class);     
        expect(custMock.getAccount()).andReturn("1111").times(1);
        replay(custMock);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.execute();
    }
}
```

I've looked into andStubReturn(), but haven't quite figured it out yet.

Thank you all for your guidance.

Comment: You could move `method1` and `method2` to another class which then can be mocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EasyMock allows partial mocking via the `EasyMock.createMockBuilder` method. Via a fluent interface you can define the methods that you want to mock.

And don't forget to call `EasyMock.verify` at the end otherwise you won't catch cases where a method call is expected but actually the method is never called.

```
@Test
public void testExecute(){
    Customer custMock = createMock(Customer.class);     
    expect(custMock.getAccount()).andReturn("1111").times(1);
    replay(custMock);

    Foo foo = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(Foo.class)
                      .addMockedMethod("method1")
                      .addMockedMethod("method2")
                      .createMock();
    foo.execute();

    verify(custMock);
}
```

Comment: Thanks eee.  I also found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592302/easymock-mock-methods-within-tested-class.  With a few tweaks, it's doing what I needed.